How to concat a string after a variable (exported) in shell script
I have two shell scripts.

SetEnvVariable.sh
MigrationOperator.sh

In SetEnvVariable.sh I'm setting a variable called CONNECT_POD_RESOURCE_NAME by doing below
export CONNECT_POD_RESOURCE_NAME="connect-200"

From MigrationOperator.sh I am calling the SetEnvVariable.sh as below
source ./SetEnvVariable.sh

Now I have a strange observation,
If in my MigrationOperator.sh I have a code like below,
echo $CONNECT_POD_RESOURCE_NAME
var=$CONNECT_POD_RESOURCE_NAME
echo $var
var+=",1/1,RUNNING"
echo $var

The output looks like,

This output is unexpected to me as I was expected that at last echo, $var should have a proper concated value.
However,
if my MigrationOperator script has the code like,
export CONNECT_POD_RESOURCE_NAME="connect-200"
echo $CONNECT_POD_RESOURCE_NAME
var=$CONNECT_POD_RESOURCE_NAME
echo $var
var+=",1/1,RUNNING"
echo $var

the output looks proper,

what I don't understand is when CONNECT_POD_RESOURCE_NAME (and later var) variable has proper value in it, how come string concatenation works fine in one case and doesn't in another case?
And what is a better way to set the variables in a separate script (here in this e.g. SetEnvVariable.sh) and still be able to use it (directly and by string manipulation) in the caller script?

Does CONNECT_POD_RESOURCE_NAME have a carriage return or some other unusual character in it? Try cat -A SetEnvVariable.sh and see what it looks like.

@tjm3772 Got it, the "SetEnvVariable" which was provided to me was not having linux compatible EOL character (probably built in windows I guess). I have corrected it and it is working now. Can you please put your comment properly in answer section so i can accept it as an answer.
